# Having trouble mapping relationships via fixtures and models with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, fixture

I'm trying to learn emberJS and I figured a good starting example would be to map the relationships between the various elements in an RPG. Each element has a name and has multiple damage modifiers, depending on what element it is being used against. For example, Fire's modifier for Water is 0.5 but it's modifier for Grass is 2.0. I thought the simplest way to store this data was like so:

```
Pokechoice.Type.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'normal',
    damages: {
        'normal': '1',
        'fire': '1',
        'water': '1',
        'grass': '1',
        'electric': '1',
        'ice': '1',
        'fighting': '1',
        'poison': '1',
        'ground': '1',
        'flying': '1',
        'psychic': '1',
        'bug': '1',
        'rock': '0.5',
        'ghost': '0',
        'dragon': '1',
        'dark': '1',
        'steel': '0.5',
        'fairy': '1'
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'fire',
    damages: {
        'normal': '1',
        'fire': '0.5',
        'water': '0.5',
        'grass': '2',
        'electric': '1',
        'ice': '2',
        'fighting': '1',
        'poison': '1',
        'ground': '1',
        'flying': '1',
        'psychic': '1',
        'bug': '2',
        'rock': '0.5',
        'ghost': '0',
        'dragon': '0.5',
        'dark': '1',
        'steel': '2',
        'fairy': '1'
    }
}
];
```

But I'm having a hard time setting up a model for it. This is what I have so far:

```
Pokechoice.Type = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    damages: DS.hasMany('Pokechoice.Damage')
});

Pokechoice.Damage = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    modifier: DS.attr('number'),
    type: DS.belongsTo('Pokechoice.Type')
});
```

Obviously it isn't working. Ideally I'd like to be able to have each Type data object contain all of its modifiers in a nested object, as shown above, but I can't find any tutorials or examples that do it this way. Any help is appreciated, I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick tips on learning ember

- Use http://emberjs.jsbin.com when demonstrating code to get help
- Use Ember-Inspector (and Chrome to be able to) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi
- Understand that ember is changing, and many examples are no longer working.

  - You can read a summary about changes here, and one is relevant to you right now: DS.hasMany('Pokechoice.Damage') should be DS.hasMnay('damage') in current ember code. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#relationships
- Use http://jsonlint.com/ or simular to verify JSON
- Use JSONView (chrome-plugin) or simular plugin for your browser to view a JSON-response
- Often google using the keywords 'ember' and 'api' together with another ember object name, like 'router', 'store', 'controller', 'view', 'model'.
- Know of http://builds.emberjs.com that has ember-latest.js and ember-data-latest.js
- Hang out in #emberjs @ freenode irc server =)

### Solution / Working example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/afojaZU/2/edit

### Hope this helps!

One of the first big (time invested) answers I've made on SO :)